# How would I write this as a Summation?

Tags: summation

I have a function n that I want to write a summation for.

How would I write this as a sum?

$ (1/n_1)+((1/n_2)*(1/n_1))+((1/n_3)*(1/n_2)*(1/n_1))+ ... $ etc.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \prod_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{n_k}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \left( \prod\limits_{j=1}^i \frac{1}{n_j} \right)$$